# Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2 in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view

I have created the following on which in can perform query with out where clause clause but when I use the following query:

```
select * 
from teacherSub 
where teacher = "te123";
```

it generates an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 2

Full code:

```
USE [SchoolRecord]
GO

/****** Object:  View [dbo].[teacherSub]    Script Date: 3/30/2015 8:32:56 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[teacherSub]
AS
  SELECT sbt.teacherID   AS teacher,
         sub.Name        AS SubjectName,
         sub.GroupID     AS groupName,
         sub.Description AS subdescription
  FROM   Subjects sub,
         SubjectTeacher sbt,
         teacherInfo te
  WHERE  sbt.teacherID = te.TeacherID
         AND sbt.SubjectID = sub.subjectID;
```

How can I apply `where` clause on above view?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Single quotes` instead of `double quotes`. `Double quotes` are used to delimit `identifiers`

```
select * from teacherSub where teacher='te123'
```

Answer (score 1):

As fireblade has explained you need to use Single Quotes for Literal Strings

Also you need to use the JOIN clause to join tables(good Practice).

**View Definition**

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[teacherSub]
AS
  SELECT sbt.teacherID   AS teacher,
         sub.Name        AS SubjectName,
         sub.GroupID     AS groupName,
         sub.Description AS subdescription
  FROM   Subjects sub
  INNER JOIN  SubjectTeacher sbt ON sbt.SubjectID = sub.subjectID
  INNER JOIN  teacherInfo te     ON sbt.teacherID = te.TeacherID;
```

**Query**

```
select * from teacherSub where teacher= 'te123';
```

Answer (score 0):

Two improvements in the query

1. Double quotes not allowed
2. Instead of = , use 'like' keyword

`select * from teacherSub where teacher LIKE 'te123'`

Comment: Your **no.2** Is that a improvement

Comment: Why, oh why, is it a bad idea to use = for string literals? You should use = for equality comparisons regardless of the data type or input.